# How to include a custom binary file in the published approot in .NET Core DNX?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm developing an **ASP.NET Core 1.0** application which I deploy to a Linux machine using Docker.

In my CI pipeline I'm publishing the project using `dnu publish`, then I build the docker image with `docker build`.

I have a static binary file that I need to use in my docker image. (It's a hotfix which I need to copy into the coreclr runtime directory.) I want to be able to access that file with a command from my `Dockerfile`.

What is the idiomatic, reliable way to make that file get copied into the output directory when I'm doing `dnu publish`? What I'm currently doing - because I couldn't find a better solution - is adding it to **wwwroot**, so it gets copied into wwwroot in the output folder.
However, I don't want that file to be publicly accessible, it would be much better to make it end up in **approot**.

The approaches I found on SO and tried, but are not working:

- Including the file in the project.json as `"contentFiles": [ "mylib.so" ]`. If I do this, I get the following error during the dnx build:
  `Error: The process cannot access the file 'C:\myapp\src\myapp.web\mylib.so' because it is being used by another process.`
- I tried to experiment with creating a custom postBuild script (found the suggestion here: [New .NET "project.json" project, copying pre-built native .dlls to the output directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33951362/new-net-project-json-project-copying-pre-built-native-dlls-to-the-output-di/33952463#33952463)), but I can't figure out where to copy the file, since I have different CI pipelines publishing the same project using different publish output directories, so I cannot hardcode the directory path into my project.json.
  Or is there a way to copy it into the build directory, which will be picked up by `dnu publish` regardless of the output directory of `publish`?

Comment: You could write an middleware to check and block access to a certain folder, i.e /bin (wwwroot/bin) or set `OnPrepareResponse` on `StaticFileOptions` (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/34669398/455493 for an example)

Comment: Good idea, thanks! It feels a bit hacky though, but I'll definitely try if I can't find a proper solution outputting the files in `approot`.